# Angular template: use "as"-generated alias in the same instruction?

Tags: angular

I have an instruction like this:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(someService.modules$ | async | filterByPurchased:true) as purchasedModules">
  some generated content
  <div *ngFor="let module of purchasedModules">{{module.name}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

But I also need to check if `purchasedModules.length > 0`. Unfortunately, `purchasedModules` is not a recognized variable in the instruction where the alias is created (so I can't just add `&& purchasedModules.length` there), why? How to do it without another `<ng-container>` with another `*ngIf`?

Comment: Why can't you do that in your Pipe ? after all puchasedModules is what returns from the Pipe. or instead have an extra pipe that just returns you the length. I do not use 'as' so Im not so sure about that.

Comment: I don't need the length of the returned array anywhere else, while `purchasedModules` is used to generate the content inside... I added it to the code example.

Comment: the way you do this is with another ng-container. why are you trying to avoid that?

Comment: Just hoped for a shorter approach...