# Angular 7 Custom Pipe that returns search text along with item Count

Tags: angular

I have a search feature for a table that uses a custom filter pipe. It returns the text correctly. However I need to also be able to return the count of Items after the filter has been applied.

I need to be able to access the Item Count within the one-on-one component so that I can apply it to a pagination calculation.

one-on-one.component.html , one-on-one.component.ts , custom filter pipe

Search bar code :

```
  <input id="tableSearch" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search.." 
  [(ngModel)]="searchText">
```

table filter :

```
     <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let obj of myArray | searchFilter:  searchText | slice: (page-1) * 
      pageSize : (page-1) * pageSize + pageSize" >
```

searchFilter comes from the custom filter pipe.
searchFilter.pipe.ts Contents  :

```
     import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
     import { NGXLogger } from 'ngx-logger';

     @Pipe({
            name: 'searchFilter'
          })
     export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

     constructor(private logger: NGXLogger){}
     /**
     * @param items object from array
     * @param term term's search
     * @param excludes array of strings which will ignored during search
     */
     transform(items: any, term: string, excludes: any = []): any {
      console.log(" the passed in params are :  items = " + items + " term = " + term + " exludes = " + excludes);
      if (!term || !items) return items;
      return SearchFilterPipe.filter(items, term , excludes);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param items List of items to filter
     * @param term  a string term to compare with every property of the list
     * @param excludes List of keys which will be ignored during search
     */
    static filter(items: Array<{ [key: string]: any }>, term: string, excludes: any): Array<{ [key: string]: any }> {

      const toCompare = term.toLowerCase();

      function checkInside(item: any, term: string) {
        for (let property in item) {
          if (item[property] === null || item[property] == undefined || excludes.includes(property)) {
            continue;
          }
          if (typeof item[property] === 'object') {
            if (checkInside(item[property], term)) {
              return true;
            }
          }
          else if (item[property].toString().toLowerCase().includes(toCompare)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }

      return items.filter(function (item) {
        return checkInside(item, term);
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass to your pipe an eventEmmiter as a third parameter that is declared in your component that will return the count of the items as an observable to which you can subscribe and react when the pipe triggers.

Comment: Please make an example here: https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @IvanMihaylov Can you show me a mock example or a link to how that works please Thanks !

Comment: I am not going to write a stackblitz for you @Steve020 . If you provide one, maybe I can look at it. Alternatively you can check out this approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59421884/angular-template-use-as-generated-alias-in-the-same-instruction?noredirect=1#comment105050939_59421884

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fakeinc-qctyhf  @IvanMihaylov

Comment: Go to the ParentComponent, to view just click on navbar link.  You will see the mock table called employee. With the search bar.  So anytime user searches the filter pipe returns matches. Need to Get the count in the Parent Component every time filter is triggered so i could use for a page item count for pagination.  I set up in case for event emmiter but I believe that will only work between two components and not between a component and a custom pipe class not sure .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly, this should work for you.

parentComponent.ts

```
    import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

    count = new Subject();

    ngOnInit(){
    this.getEmployees();
    this.count.subscribe(c => console.log('Counting', c));
    console.log("Count " + this.countVar);
  }
```

parentComponent.html

```
<tbody>
          <ng-container *ngFor = "let obj of employees | searchFilter:  searchText: count" #countVar>
            <tr>
              <td>{{obj.code}}</td>
              <td>{{obj.name}}</td>
              <td>{{obj.gender}}</td>
              <td>{{obj.salary}}</td>
              <td>{{obj.dob}}</td>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>
         Showing {{count | async}} Employees
        <!-- Showing {{searchResult.length}} Employees -->
</tbody>
```

pipe.ts

```
 import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(){}
       transform(items: any, term: string, count , excludes: any = []): any {
      if (!term || !items) return items;
      return SearchFilterPipe.filter(items, term , count, excludes);
    }
    static filter(items: Array<{ [key: string]: any }>, term: string, count, excludes: any): Array<{ [key: string]: any }> {

      console.log(term);
      const toCompare = term.toLowerCase();

      function checkInside(item: any, term: string) {
        for (let property in item) {
          if (item[property] === null || item[property] == undefined || excludes.includes(property)) {
            continue;
          }
          if (typeof item[property] === 'object') {
            if (checkInside(item[property], term)) {
              return true;
            }
          }
          else if (item[property].toString().toLowerCase().includes(toCompare)) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
      const newArr = items.filter(function (item) {
        return checkInside(item, term);
      });

      count.next(newArr.length);
      return newArr;
    }

}
```